# how to restrict maximum number of files for a folder

Tags: php, laravel

Actually iam dumping a database file through php in an export folder which i created.
Here i want to keep only latest ten sql files in export folder kind of FIFO way.
I do not want too over populate the folder and want to restrict it too ten latest files.
How to do it ?

Comment: Delete the 11th file in the same code that dumps the database file.

Answer (score 0):

First grab all the files using `glob` for instance, then determine if there are ten or more files in the directory. After that check the `mtime` (modified time) for each and delete the oldest one.

```
$file_pattern = '/path/to/directory/and/files/*';
$filenames = glob( $file_pattern );

if ( count( $filenames ) > 9 ) {
    // While there are ten or more files.
    while ( count( glob( $file_pattern ) ) > 9 ) {
        $oldest_file = null;

        // Grab the unix timestamp of *now*, as filemtime returns a unix timestamp too.
        $current_oldest_time = time();

        foreach ( $filenames as $filename ) {
            $filetime = filemtime( $filename );

            if ( $filetime < $current_oldest_time ) {
                $current_oldest = $filetime;
                $oldest_file = $filename;
            }
        }

        // After the foreach you'll have the filename of the oldest file (remove it),:
        unlink( $oldest_file );

        // Or null if something went wrong (break out of the loop):
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can delete files with the unlink function : http://php.net/manual/de/function.unlink.php

you just have to find the oldest file in your directory